# QGIS import data source mbtiles error as raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, mbtiles, data-source

I imported a mbtiles that I created last time. But when I import it as the Raster Layer, it show the error like this,
Error:

```
Unsupported Data Source: C:\ ... LTI2.mbtiles is not a supported raster data source zoom_level > 22 not supported
```

Any idea?

Edit: the mbtiles should contain something like this
[image]

Comment: What does `gdalinfo LTI2.mbtiles` show?

Comment: Do you mean that "the mbtiles should contain something like this", but it doesn't?

Comment: What is the maximum zoom level in your mbtiles? If it is > 22, that is probably a good place to start